# Autodesk Forge Viewer : Does viewer.setThemingColor work on a converted DWG file?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-viewer

viewer.setThemingColor works fine for me to change the color of something in a revit to svf file

but when i try and use it for a DWG to SVF conversion it does nothing.

```
oViewer.setThemingColor(1604, new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 1,1));
```

Note one thing I am assuming is that the dbId that the mouse click does for seletion is the same dbId I need to use for setThemingColor

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That should work... Are you sure about you are passing a correct dbId? In fact it works on my side.

You can give it a try on [my viewer playground](http://viewer.autodesk.io/node/gallery/#/extension-editor?id=54464d43af600b5c0a872551). It could be that there is an issue specific to your model, in which case you could share that design with us. Privately if needed.

Here is my test code:

```
AutodeskNamespace("Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension");

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic = function (viewer, options) {

  Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);

  var _this = this;

  _this.load = function () {

    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function(e){

      if(e.dbIdArray.length) {
        var dbId = e.dbIdArray[0];
        console.log('DbId: ' + dbId);
        viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 1,1));
      }
    })

    return true;
  };

  _this.unload = function () {

    return true;
  };
};

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype =
  Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype.constructor =
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic;

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
  "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic",
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Your example sort of works for me.  (WORKS)If I select an object then unselect it the color of the converted DWG polygon will change.  

(FAILS)If i set the value directly outside of the SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT then the color does not change until I do something like the selection clicking.

I am wondering if there is some state change that needs to be called that "invalidates" the colors so that they need to reset/rerendered?

Comment: How about you try that after you set the themingColor: "viewer.impl.invalidate(false, false, true)" ?