# Viewer automatically change material to default

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a problem with changes of material of some elements

when geometry is loaded:

```
_this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
    changeModelMaterial()
});

...

const changeModelMaterial = () => {
    const grey = new THREE.Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    let dbIds = getDbIds()
    changeAllElementsMaterial(grey)
    setMaterialOfDbIds(dbIds)
}
```

code that i`m using to change material:

```
const changeAllElementsMaterial = (color) => {
    const fragmentList = _this.viewer.model.getFragmentList();
    for (let materialId of fragmentList.materialids) {
        if (fragmentList.materialmap[materialId]) {
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].map = null
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].color = color
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].needsUpdate = true;
        }
    }
    _this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}

const setMaterialOfDbIds = (dbIds) => {
    var color_diffuse = 0xAB00EE;
    var color_specular = 0xEEABEE;
    var colorM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: color_diffuse,
        specular: color_specular
    });
    _this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(
        'ADN-Material-' +
        "common color material",  // or a GUID
        colorM,
        true);

   for (let dbId of dbIds) {
       _this.viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
           _this.viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, colorM);

       });
   }
   _this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

It works, because I see that materials of model are changed, but the problem is that materials back to default after ~1-2 sec.

After this I cannot change material even with run this code manually.

Question is why Viewer is locking material change after this 2 sec, how to prevent it

And maybe you will be able to tell me what i can do better with material changes, eg. maybe something better that running my code after GEOMETRY_LOAD. The best would be change material before first render of model

........

hint:

when change event from GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT to OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT "sometimes" but only sometimes it works well (materials stay to the end of working with model), but mostly when i run my method after OBJECT_TREE_CREATED it not working (even not working by run it manually, materials are in some way locked). So I suspect that problem is between time of GEOMETRY_LOAD and OBJECT_TREE_CREATED

I will be grateful for any help

==============================full code==============================

index.html

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>
    <button id="open-nav-button" onClick="showDocInfo()">test</button>
</div>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/autodesk-viewer.js"></script>
<script src="js/extension/test-extension.js"></script>

<script>
    const autodeskViewer = new AutodeskViewer()
    const showDocInfo = () => {
        autodeskViewer.showDocInfo()
    }
</script>
```

autodesk-viewer.js

```
var AutodeskViewer = (function () {
function AutodeskViewer() {
    var _this = this;
    this.urn = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLTFzcGduazdqcWpxdjhmYXV0YmNzd2R0cGdvN3VtNWY1L1BPQy1Gb3JnZS1JVCUyMDIwMTclMjBSdWNoXzEwMDUxNy5ud2Q';

    this.initializeViewer = function (containerId, documentId) {
        _this.viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication(containerId);
        var config = {
            extensions: ['TestExtension']
        };
        _this.viewerApp.registerViewer(_this.viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config);
        _this.viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, _this.onDocumentLoadSuccess, _this.onDocumentLoadFailure);
    }

    this.onDocumentLoadSuccess = function (doc) {
        const viewables = _this.viewerApp.bubble.search(av.BubbleNode.MODEL_NODE);
        if (viewables.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        _this.viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, _this.onItemLoadSuccess, _this.onItemLoadFail);
        _this.viewer3d = _this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
    }

    this.onDocumentLoadFailure = (viewerErrorCode) => {}

    this.onItemLoadSuccess = (viewer) => {
        _this.viewer = viewer
    }

    this.onItemLoadFail = (errorCode) => {}

    this.initialize = () => {
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            getAccessToken: _this.getToken,
            refreshToken: _this.getToken
        };
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, _this.initCallback);
    };

    this.initCallback = function () {
        _this.initializeViewer('MyViewerDiv', _this.urn, '3d');
    };
    this.getToken = function (onGetAccessToken) {
        $.get("forge/oauth/token")
            .done(function (data) {
                token = data
                onGetAccessToken(token, 60 * 60);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR', error);
            });
    };

    this.showDocInfo = function () {};
    this.initialize();
}

return AutodeskViewer;
}());
```

test-extension.js

```
var _self;
var _viewer;
var _tempValue = 0;

function TestExtension(viewer, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
    _self = this;
    _viewer = viewer;
}

const changeModelMaterial = () => {
    // _tempValue++;
    // if (_tempValue == 2) {
    const elements = [4340, 4342, 4344, 4346, 4348, 4367, 4371, 4375, 4380, 4452, 4468, 4488, 4503, 4517, 4520, 4522, 4524, 4526, 4528, 4530]

    changeAllElementsMaterial(new THREE.Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    setMaterialOfDbIds(elements)
    _tempValue = 0
    // }
}

const changeAllElementsMaterial = (color) => {
    var fragmentList = _viewer.model.getFragmentList();
    for (let materialId of fragmentList.materialids) {
        if (fragmentList.materialmap[materialId]) {
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].map = null
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].color = color
            fragmentList.materialmap[materialId].needsUpdate = true;
        }
    }
    _viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}

const setMaterialOfDbIds = (dbIds) => {
    var colorM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: new THREE.Color(0xAB00EE)
    });

    for (let dbId of dbIds) {
        _viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
            _viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, colorM);

        });
    }
    _viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}

TestExtension.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);
TestExtension.prototype.constructor = TestExtension;

TestExtension.prototype.load = function () {
    _viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, changeModelMaterial)
    // _viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, changeModelMaterial)
    return true
};

TestExtension.prototype.unload = function () {
    return true
};

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('TestExtension', TestExtension);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, quite accidentally... from other thing i tried to do

before:

```
    const setMaterialOfDbIds = (dbIds) => {
        var color_diffuse = 0xAB00EE;
        var color_specular = 0xEEABEE;
        var colorM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: color_diffuse,
            specular: color_specular
        });
        _this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial("common color material", colorM, true);

        for (let dbId of dbIds) {
            _this.viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
                _this.viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, colorM);
            });
        }
        _this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
    }
```

after

```
    const setMaterialOfDbIds = (dbIds) => {
        var color_diffuse = 0xAB00EE;
        var color_specular = 0xEEABEE;
        var colorM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: color_diffuse,
            specular: color_specular
        });
        _this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial("common color material", colorM, true);

        for (let dbId of dbIds) {
            _this.viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
                _this.viewer.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId, colorM);
                var fragProxy = _this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(_this.viewer.model, fragId)
                fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
            });
        }
        _this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
    }
```

Really I don`t know why adding

```
var fragProxy = _this.viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(_this.viewer.model, fragId)
fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()
```

made the difference, i didn`t saw anything like that in any example of updating material. 
What is interesting this code is running for only few elements in model, but it works for even those elements that materials changed before (in changeAllElementsMaterial method).

@Philippe Leefsma if you understand it pls tell something more why it works

Answer (score 0):

So far I cannot reproduce the issue on my side, I am using the following code (ES7) extracted from that extension: [Viewing.Extension.Material](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Material)

```
createColorMaterial (color) {

  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    specular: new THREE.Color(color),
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    reflectivity: 0.0,
    color
  })

  const materials = this.viewer.impl.getMaterials()

  materials.addMaterial(
    this.guid(),
    material,
    true)

  return material
}

async onModelCompletedLoad() {

  const material = this.createColorMaterial(0xFF0000)

  const model = this.viewer.model

  const fragIds = await Toolkit.getFragIds(model)

  fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {

    model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(
      fragId, material)
  })

  this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)
}
```

The `onModelCompletedLoad` is a custom event fired when both `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` and `OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` have been fired.

Take a look at this article for more details: [Asynchronous viewer events notification](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/asynchronous-viewer-events-notification.html)

I doubt you can easily change the materials before the model is first rendered, however you could use a custom overlay that hides the model until your custom logic has performed all required steps, this is the approach I am using in my demos at: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator

After loading a model, all custom materials are being persisted fine:

[image]

The material extension can be tested live from [there](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=59d52c493096fb09f0bfdcf2).

Hope that helps

Comment: ok, now I`m doing my stuff after two events (OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT and GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT) are fired, and with this change it still have same behavior.

I think that at first i have to find out why materials can be changed only in first 2-3 sec

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible sample I will take a look. Did you try my material demo? Definitely works fine there, so you must be doing something wrong ... You can also take a look at viewer.setThemingColor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534862/autodesk-forge-viewer-does-viewer-setthemingcolor-work-on-a-converted-dwg-file

Comment: I updated my question, now you can see all code im using, you can try it by your own. Now when extension will load im adding event listener for OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT. So what i want to do work only sometimes. When you uncomment other listener from load method and  uncoment simple trick from changeModelMaterial method then you should see that materials are updated and then after ~2 sec are reverted to default ones.